# Should incoming parameters be mapped to an enum?

Tags: c#, theory

Im currently working on a system, and one of the methods that is provided as part of a interface  receives the state of a country as a string -

```
public DoStuff(string state)
{

//do stuff
}
```

The state can only be one of a range of previously known values.I understand that it would be better served to replace the string parameter with an enum parameter but due to some factors out of my control, the interface needs to remain as it is.

My question is this: 
Generally is it better to map strings to an enum as soon as possible ( if it can be done) and from that point on use the enumarated type instead of the string? Or is it better to leave it as a string and whenever something is dependent on the value of the state, to use a switch statement instead?

Comment: List out what you think are the pros. List out what you think are the cons. See if the pros outweigh the cons.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer to use enums whenever and as soon as it is possible. It saves a lot of errors in development, and ensures that the code is cleaner and easier to understand.

The enum also functions as an explicit definition of the different states that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a fixed and known set of data then go for Enum as soon as possible. This is a good design practice and very easy for your team to understand.